# Can an android application be loaded from the SD card?

Tags: android

Is there something like a an Android file explorer so that the application could be installed from an SD card on versions older than 2.2 if the signed .apk file was manually copied onto the SD card? (Kind of like installing from a web page.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Astro file manager (installed from the market) can do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  you will need a file manager application, and also need to change the 'Unknown Sources' setting on your phone.  Details here:

- [How to Install Non-Market Apps on Your Android Device](http://www.androidapk.net/?p=12)

Comment: And they will need to not have one of the AT&T phones on which that item was removed from the settings menu (however they can still sideload apps over USB)